# Handle field with same names but different table in Mapping

Tags: mapping, informatica, field-names

I have the following SQL:

```
select zcactcls.name "ACCOUNT_CLASS",
zcpatcls.name "PATIENT_CLASS",
zcsvc.name "SERVICE"
```

The name field is used multiple times by different tables.  In the joiner, the fields are noted as name, name1, name2.  It is hard to figure out which of these name fields belong to which table.  How can I alias these name fields to be "Account_Class", "Patient_Class", and "Service" within the mapping.

[Multiple Name Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGE7K.png)

Comment: When I change the column names in the Source Qualifier or a joiner transformation, the names are not updated in my existing transformations such as filters and expressions. Is there a way to change the column names and have the existing transformations automatically update with the new name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename the ports - right after the `Source Qualifier`. Or if you use SQL Override, simply use SQL aliases and name the ports properly right in the `Source Qualifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the fields in your SQ to match the field names in your SQL.